# Import Specific Column Data into Different MYSQL Tables from CSV using Python

Tags: python, mysql, csv, mysql-python

I have a csv file with many columns and I want to import two to one table, ten to another, and ten to another still. How could I modify the code below to be selective like that? I was thinking of using if/elif statements to identify columns by their first row data, but I'm not sure that's the best/easiest solution.

```
import csv
import MySQLdb
# open the connection to the MySQL server.
# using MySQLdb
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='hostinfo',
    user='myusername',
    passwd='mypw',
    db='mydatabase')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
# read the presidents.csv file using the python
# csv module http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html
csv_data = csv.reader(file('CHN.csv'))
# execute the for clicle and insert the csv into the
# database.
for row in csv_data:

    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO INDICATORS (INDICATORNAME, INDICATORCODE)
                  VALUES (%s, %s)''', row)
#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Import to MySQL is over"
```

Comment: so you want to import element 0 and 1 to table1, 2 through 11 to table2, 12 to 12 to table3? Or is there any variability? What's special about the first row data? Do you have an example?

Comment: I'm new to this so thanks for your help and patience. I have a csv with over 50 columns. I want to pull the first two columns into a MySQL table called Indicators. I want to pull the next 10 columns into another table called Sixties. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Here is an example of the first row of data (but not all columns because it goes to 2012): Indicator Name Indicator Code 1960 1961 1962 1963 1964 1965 1966 1967 1968

Answer (score 0):

Define your SQL strings first:

```
insert_indicators = '''INSERT INTO INDICATORS (INDICATORNAME, INDICATORCODE)
                       VALUES (%s, %s)'''
insert_sixties = 'INSERT INTO Sixties (...) VALUES (%s)' % (','.join(['%s']*10))
insert_seventies = 'INSERT INTO Seventies (...) VALUES (%s)' % (','.join(['%s']*10))
```

Then use them in the `for-loop` like this:

```
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute(insert_indicators, row[:2])
    cursor.execute(insert_sixties, row[2:12])
    cursor.execute(insert_seventies, row[12:22])
```

Note that it may be a bad idea to have two different tables with essentially the same structure. Instead of having a `Sixties` table and (presumably) a `Seventies` table, it might be nicer to have one  table, with a `Decade` column which can hold [enumerated values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) such as `'Sixties'` or `'Seventies'`.

By having all the data in one table, you'll be able to express some kinds of queries more easily (without having to repeat essentially the same query multiple times, once for each table.)

Comment: Thanks for this. To make sure I understand, would row[0] == Indicator Name? Would row[2:12] == 1960 through 1970?

Comment: Yes,... sort of. Each time through the loop `row` will be a tuple of values, representing one row from the csv. `row[0]` is the first value in the tuple. `row[2:12]` is the third through twelfth values in the tuple.

Comment: So in the for loop why do you overlap with row[:2] followed by row[2:12] and again with row[12:22]?

Wouldn't that grab tuples 2 and 12 twice each?

Comment: Like Python ranges, Python slices are half-open intervals. `row[2:12]` means `row[2]` through `row[11]`. `row[12:22]` means `row[12]` through `row[21]`. This might seem odd at first, but it has certain advantages, such as making it easy to tell how many items are in a slice (subtracting 12-2 tells you there are 10 items), and it helps with composing expressions for adjacent slices such as `row[i:j]` and `row[j:k]` without having to stick `+1`s in your code.

Comment: By the way, I encourage you to use a Python interactive shell or even stick `print` statements in your code to explore the values of various expressions. This is my number one tool for exploring Python and figuring out how code works.